# MVVM light Messenger issue with VS2017 15.5.2

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2017, anonymous-function

Since the latest VS2017 (15.5.2) update we have discovert an issue with the MVVM light Messenger. If we register for messages using a anonymous-function like this

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessageObject>(this, () => { DoSomething(); });
```

we won't receive the messages. But if we do it with a regular function it works.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessageObject>(this, HandleMessage);
```

and

```
private void HandleMessage()
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what has changed? Is this a general issue with anonymous-functions?

Comment: What makes you think it is related to the version of VS? Didn't you change the target framework or updated some package?

Comment: The issue appeared suddenly on all brunches even the old ones. Luckily not all developers have updated their machines at the same time. So we had the same code base but a different outcome, depending on the VS version. After updateing a VS which haven't had the issue, we ran into the same problem.